# How to discover the TOR Browser version in a running instance?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

From a running instance of the TOR Browser, how can I show its version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the "Burger" Menu (looks like ≡)
2. Click on the question mark/help button at the bottom of the "Burger" Menu
3. From there, select "About Tor Browser".

This should open up a new window which will display which version of Tor Browser you are using.